# getting memory leak with fabric and twitter in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-fabric

[image]  I am getting memory leak at line `[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit,TwitterKit]]`; in instrument, in the following code. How to get ride from this.

```
if (analyticsEnabled) {
            [WizRocket notifyApplicationLaunchedWithOptions:launchOptions];
            [Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
            [Flurry startSession:KFlurryAnalyticsAPIKey];
            [Flurry setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:NO];
            [Flurry setSessionReportsOnPauseEnabled:NO];

        }


        [Appirater setAppId:@""];
        [Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:7];
        [Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:10];
        [Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:-1];
        [Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:30];
        [Appirater setDebug:NO];
        [Appirater appLaunched:YES];
     [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit,TwitterKit]];
```

Comment: check whether Fabric is deallocated before that line...enable zombies in ur project and check once @Murali mohan Proddatur

Comment: Fabric is third party sdk with only Fabric.h file.How can i check whether that is deallocated or not? if our app is crashed at that time only we have to use zombie right? but app is working. But instrument is showing leak

Comment: once check in net how to enable Zombie in xcode then run the code again, then u MAY get log report of that crash

Comment: i did not get crash @satya . in instrument i am getting a big redline .

Comment: Show the details from Instruments.  What is being leaked? Also aren't you using 2 crash reporters here?

Comment: please check the screen shot @Droppy

Comment: yes i am using crash reporter i.e Crashlytics

Comment: were you able to have it fixed ?

Comment: @Murali mohan Proddatur, same problem, my apps working fine, but check in instrument it has memory leak, you have got any solution. +1.

Comment: i too got this same leak...

Comment: i did not get any solution. if anybody got please reply with answer.

Comment: Are you using last versions? According to this: https://twittercommunity.com/t/fabric-has-memory-leaks-and-crashes-when-lauching-app/43990 Some of the leaks in prior versions have been fixed.